# Select option(s) - to change - upon typing data into external input field?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this pure HTML code..

```
<select id="itemlist">
<option value = "1">Domes</option>
<option value = "2">Lots</option>
<option value = "3">Dot games</option>
<option value = "4">Bikes</option>
and so on...
</select>
<input id="itemlist_change" type="text" size="5"/>
```

Upon typing "d" (or "do") into an input field `id="itemlist_change"` I wish for jquery just to show this..

```
<select id="itemlist">
<option value = "1">Domes</option>
<option value = "3">Dot games</option>
</select>
```

It is some sort of useful `select` search function. Any simple jquery stuff for this? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#itemlist_change').on('keyup blur', function() {

  var search = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

  $('#itemlist option')
    .show()
    .filter(function() {
      return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(search) < 0;
    })
    .hide();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<select id="itemlist">
  <option value="1">Domes</option>
  <option value="2">Lots</option>
  <option value="3">Dot games</option>
  <option value="4">Bikes</option>
</select>
<input id="itemlist_change" type="text" size="5" />
```

Comment: Perfect, thx 4castle!!!! PS: can these other options simply disappear, instead of being disabled?

Comment: Yes, disabling is probably not desired. It would actually keep the data from being submitted if it wasn't matched by what was in the text box.

Comment: Yes, and its more useful this way since number of options is huge. Thank you so much for your code 4castle again, so simple and great!

Comment: I wasn't sure if you wanted to search based on what the option starts with or based on if the option contains the text. i.e if you search `o`, I'm not sure if it's currently giving what you expect. The filter isn't very sophisticated, but it's easy to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery Select2 plugin

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myDropdown").select2();
    });
</script>

<select id="myDropdown">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

[(Source)](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Comment: Hey thx but I wish to avoid plugin(s) for this matter. Maybe there is something less code available. Or at least JS cross browser supported.